# Creating Button Programatically and then using it's id to perform something using onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to Create a Button Programatically and then using it's id to perform something using `onclicklistener`.if i use `setId()` in button what am i supposed to do in `onClick()` i mean how can i get ID  to use like`(v.getId()== ???)` please Help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this way

```
Button b1 = new Button(context);
b1.setId(1);
b1.setOnclickListener(new MyListener());

Button b2 = new Button(context);
b2.setId(2);
b2.setOnclickListener(new MyListener());

Button b3 = new Button(context);
b3.setId(3);
b3.setOnclickListener(new MyListener());

class MyListener implements OnClickListener{
     public void onClick(View v){
          int id = v.getId();
          Log.v("button id",""+id); 
          // use here with switch or if condition with id
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply code under the line where you define your button.like:

```
Button b=new Button(context);
b.setId(<some number>);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // do stuff here                
    }
});
```